# Inner join in C# with lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join, lambda

I'm new to LINQ and Lambda. I want to make query that will get me for every studyYear (1,2,3) students who are studying that year. I've done it without Lambda but I really want to know how to do it with lambda.

```
            var res = from s in db.student
                  join u in db.EnrolledYear
                  on s.ID equals u.studentID
                  join g in db.studyYear
                  on u.studyYearID equals g.ID
                  select new
                  {
                      Year = g.year,
                      StudentFName = s.FirstName
                      StudentLName = s.LastName
                  };
```

I checked out other examples with lambda but I didn't really understand .
What I managed is to make inner join between student and enrolled year. Now I don't understand how to finish inner join between enrolled year and study year.
I'm stuck here, I need to make one more join:

```
var res = db.EnrolledYear.Join(db.student,
                  u => u.studentID, s => s.ID,
                  (enroll, student) => new
                  {
                      Godina = enroll.year,
                      FName = student.FirstName
                      LName = student.LastName
                  })
                  .Join(.....?)
```

[image: Picture in imgur of relations in database:]

Comment: Just curious: Do you have a working SQL query that gets you the results you want? When trying to compose a complex query in LINQ, I find it useful to work from a proven SQL query.

Comment: Yes, I have. But I didn't do LINQ with lambda on multiple tables before, just tried to understand with some examples, now I wanted to learn and use it

Comment: Unless this is purely scientific interest (to see how 3 tables join works) I would not break your db model to 3 tables. To be precise, StudyYear table is simply meaningless; it has one column "year" that is probably of the same size as the ID for this table. Well, the ID eventually might have even bigger size (can't imagine year going beyond 10000, while ID==count of all-time students); it's meaningless in terms of storage optimization. Correct location for this information would be inside of EnrolledYear table; look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every clause in a query will correspond to a lambda call. Just go down to every clause and convert to an appropriate call.

This particular query could be written like so:

```
db.student
    .Join(db.EnrolledYear, s => s.ID, u => u.studentID, (s, u) => new { s, u })
    .Join(db.studyYear, x => x.u.studyYearID, g => g.ID, (x, g) => new { x.s, x.u, g })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Year = x.g.year,
        StudentFName = x.s.FirstName,
        StudentLName = x.s.LastName,
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Include`.

Something like:

```
db.students.Include(x => x.EnrolledYears).ThenInclude(x=>x.StudyYear).Select(new ...)
```